# Better way to remove redundancy between two columns of a data frame in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, apply

If I have a data frame which contains one column, name, and another, site, and I want to determine the number of unique name to site relationships.

I've written the following script. It works but feels bodged and is slow for my real data:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("dave", "bob", "dave", "john", "fred", "dave"), site = c(1,2,2,1,1,1))
redun = vector()
for (i in 1:length(df$name)){
  redun[i] = paste(df$name[i], df$site[i])
}
uniq = length(unique(redun))
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to loop? `length(unique(paste0(df$name,df$site)))` should do the job.

Comment: Many thanks! Its because the real version of df has many columns, not just two, so I got a bit confused and weird about it. Thanks again.

Comment: `table(df$name, df$site)` also should help in finding this relation (probably not straightforward for your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to check `? duplicated`.

```
> duplicated( df )
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> sum( !duplicated( df ) )
[1] 5
```

**EDIT** or according to your comment in the original Post:

```
> duplicated( df[ c("name", "site" ) ] )
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> sum( !duplicated( df[ c("name", "site" ) ] ) )
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop, just do:

```
length(unique(with(df, paste(name, site))))
```

Or even shorter (and I think faster too) is:

```
nrow(unique(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate. This will handily tell you who has a how many unique sites to their name;

```
aggregate( site ~ name , data = df , function(x) length( unique(x) ) )
#  name site
#1  bob    1
#2 dave    2
#3 fred    1
#4 john    1
```

And if you want to know how many unique sites by name, just sum:

```
sum(aggregate( site ~ name , data = df , function(x) length( unique(x) ) )$site)
[1] 5
```

Comment: This was really great for something else I wanted to know about my data too so thank you!